# Integrate Azure service-bus with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azureservicebus

I have used Spring Boot to create a new Subscriber for a topic and apply a custom filter to it. I establish a connection to create a subscriber using the connectionString.

Although I have successfully created the Subscriber,but the custom filter has not been applied. My requirement is to create a new Subscriber and attach a correlation custom filter to it.

Additionally, I have used **v7.14.0** of service-bus.
The sample code is given below:

```
final String connectionString = "";

        // create connection
        ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .buildClient();

        // create filter
        CreateRuleOptions ruleOptions = new CreateRuleOptions();
        CorrelationRuleFilter correlationFilter = new CorrelationRuleFilter();
        correlationFilter.getProperties().put("X number", "12345");  // Here I set custom correlation filter.
        ruleOptions.setFilter(correlationFilter);

        //create subscription
        CreateSubscriptionOptions subscriptionOptions = new CreateSubscriptionOptions()
                .setAutoDeleteOnIdle(Duration.ofDays(7))
                .setMaxDeliveryCount(10)
                .setDefaultMessageTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(2))
                .setUserMetadata("some metadata");

        adminClient.createSubscription("topic name", "subscriber", "Rule name", subscriptionOptions, ruleOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Although I have successfully created the Subscriber, the custom filter has not been applied. My requirement is to create a new Subscriber and attach a correlation custom filter to it.

**I tried in my environment and got the same results.**

Initially, I tried with Java code to create a subscription with a correlation filter but, it created only a subscription and not creating a filter may we cannot do this in Java or it may be a bug.

For alternation, create the subscription first and you can use the below Java code to create the correlation filter.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.*;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.CorrelationRuleFilter;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.CreateRuleOptions;


public final class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String connectionString = "xxxxx";
        ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
        
        CorrelationRuleFilter filter = new CorrelationRuleFilter();
        filter.getProperties().put("eventType", "order.created");
        filter.getProperties().put("eventTypeVersion", 1);
        filter.getProperties().put("label","important");

        adminClient.createRule("topic326","rule326","subscription326",new CreateRuleOptions(filter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[CorrelationFilter Class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.rules.correlationfilter?view=azure-java-stable)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your solution works well for me too. However, I believe it would be even better if both the subscriber and correlation filter were created using the one method call(That's my requirement).